# Database designing help for billing system

Tags: sql-server

I am developing a Electronic Bill Payment System for a bank which has more than 100 customers subscribing for Electronic Bill Payment.

I have a table in which I am creating profile for customer like the following.

### Customer Table

Customer_ID  (Primary key)
Customer_Name
Address
Phone

### Bill_Master

1. Customer_ID
2. Enrollment_Date
3. UtilityCompany_ID
4. Bill_Generation_Date (lets say 18th of every month)
5. Bill_Due_Date (lets say 27th of every month)
6. Our_CutOff_Date (when the bank will generate the bill for payment)

I have created the customer along with clue that which utility company's bill generates on which date and what will be the due date of EVERY MONTH.

I want to create an interface where the user will see the entries of all the customers whoz date is due for bill generation and after that user will click on the particular entry and generate the bill manually by entering the amount and other details so for this I am clueless how to find out which customer's utility company bill is due for generation..

Any help how should I design it and query of it? or would be a automatic procedure like job or something which will do it.

thanks

Comment: What format are your dates stored in?

Comment: how did you decided that these fields are needed, if you dont have an idea of what query to use?

Answer (score 0):

Well if its a query you need to generate bills that are due 27th of every month and also find the customer's utility company, then you can try this -

```
SELECT A.Customer_Name, B.UtilityCompany_ID FROM
Customer A inner join Bill_Master B on A.Customer_ID = B.Customer_ID
WHERE Bill_Due_Date BETWEEN GETDATE() AND DATEADD(MONTH,-1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: I started to write this up too, but we need to know his format for Bill_Due_Date first - if it's a date or datetime we need to remove the year.  If it's just an int for the day of the month it's a whole different set of logic.

Comment: Keng its not a home work its a electronic bill payment system i am writing for a bank. I've never worked for billing system so just wondering if it can be solved through a mere query or need to create a SQLSERVER Job...need opinions actually and the way. Oh my bill date would be the DAY OF THE MONTH only.

Comment: So are you using an int for your bill date for e.g. 27 for 27/3/2010 ? If so you will have to modify the where clause appropriately. But, I would advice you to use datetime instead of an int.

Comment: but different utility companies have different billing dates and the main concern is the date not the month and year. I will indeed pick it through the date picker control of asp.net so it would return the date only. But my main design concern is that is it going to be a SQLJOB or query? I guess i need to come up with a stored procedure which will loop through every customer and their utility companies...check their due date and check the entry in billing table if exist then leave otherwise insert into that table and mark for "billing ready" what do you think?

Comment: If you create a stored procedure as you mentioned, when do you plan to execute this? If you want to execute this based on user input then a stored procedure sounds fine. If this is a recurring event, then you can have a job running instead.

Comment: Just make a view for this.  Make a view based on the above query, and you query the view to get the current list of customers and bills that need to be generated.

Comment: there will be no user input Pavenred. I think I will execute this job every night so every morning the billing data would be available to the user. how about that?