# Date Logic Question

Tags: business-logic, application-design

I am developing a billing system and need help as i am clueless here. I have some customers and their utility bill payment is responsibility of my bank. In my system I am registering customers with their utility company along with the following data.

### **Biller Table

### Customer Josh & Co.

Utility Company A

Consumer #............... AL12111
Bill Generation Date .... 07th of every month
Bill Due Date ........... 18th of every month
Cut off Date of my bank.. 12th of every month

Now on bill generation screen I am taking inputs like the following.

Consumer # ...... AL12111

Bill Entry Date.. 29-10-2010 (Readonly field System Date)

Customer .... Josh & Co.

Billing Month .... October

Amount Due ... 5,000 US$

Now my problem is that how do i figure out if accountant is generating bill before due date or not but in biller table i dont have month and year just the date of month.

I would appreciate your help and solution advise..

thanks

Comment: Duplicate...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070281/database-designing-help-for-billing-system

Comment: No offense but: "I am clueless" and "responsibility of my bank" don't sound good.  Please say this is homework.

Comment: aBitObvious I m junior programmer and just started my programming career n its not a homework..is it a problem learning thru forums? humm

Comment: He is concerned (as I am) that someone who doesn't know SQL very well is helping design an application for a financial institution since redundancy and accuracy will be very important.

Comment: I'd expect a bank to have the resources to provide in-house support to new junior programmers for questions of this type.

Comment: Working in a team..its my small part and this a way how every individual moves ahead with the help of others..I guess it shouldnt be a major concern or write in forum's FAQ "Newbies are not allowed to post questions here"..

Comment: @user342944 - Two things.  1 - Newbies are encouraged to post here.  His concern was with the scope of what you are working on and the sensitivity.  If someone posted they were new to coding but were working for the government to develop an application to control nuclear weapons I would be worried.  In your case I just want to make sure I don't use your bank :)  2 - What do you need to know that was not answered in your prior question?

Comment: lol@JNK ..well in my profile i am keeping all dates (dd) only (for every month) and while entering the data i have system date (billing month) so wanted to know how to compare if entering before due date or after due date of current month

Comment: You would use the `DATEPART` function...check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: Well so far i made it work upto certain level

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a SQL Server question or even a programming question - this is a business question that can only be answered by your business analyst/stakeholder.

To expand, you have a date of entry yyyy-mm-dd (lets call that dt_entry, a datetime) and a day of month which the bill is due, lets call that d (an integer).

You would manufacture a date in the same month as the date of entry (note that for dates near the end of the month, you will need to get some clarification from the business as to what the rules are - perhaps using some kind of sliding window).

So the due date in date form would be dt_entry - DAY(dt_entry) + d (SQL Server datetime can use simple integer addition for days, no need for DATEADD).

You can see where this will cause a problem near the end of the month, because d will be small (say 1), and the entry date will be large, (say 31) and then the hypothetical due date is really the next month.  But what if a person is paying really early (like the 5th for a due date of the 25th)?

Also, you may need to consider the short months, since there cannot be a 31st in February on which to be due.

All these are programming problems which only have business answers.

Comment: i am asking for a logic as per the structure..neway thanks to all of you who tried to convince me that i shouldnt throw questions here and learn logic building.

Comment: @user342944 I have expanded on why you need business input.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE [sp_BillDateCheck]
 @CURMONTH VARCHAR(3),
 @MONTHNUM INT OUTPUT,
 @EBDATEMATCH VARCHAR(90) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @ENTRYDATE DATETIME
   SELECT @ENTRYDATE = GETDATE() --GET CURRENT ENTRY DATE

--GET MONTH NUMBER BY GIVING MONTH NAME
   SELECT @MONTHNUM = DATEPART(mm,CAST(@CURMONTH + ' 1900' AS DATETIME))

IF DATEPART(MONTH, @ENTRYDATE) = @MONTHNUM
      SELECT @EBDATEMATCH = 'ENTRY DATE AND BILLING MONTH ARE SAME'

IF DATEPART(MONTH, @ENTRYDATE) <  @MONTHNUM
      SELECT @EBDATEMATCH = 'ENTRY DATE IS LESS THAN BILLING MONTH'

IF DATEPART(MONTH, @ENTRYDATE) >  @MONTHNUM
      SELECT @EBDATEMATCH = 'ENTRY DATE IS GREATER THAN BILLING MONTH'
END
GO`

thanks to JNK for providing DATEPART hint. I am not a pee brain for sure